# Mister Captain, will your ship sink?

Tags: forms-of-address

"President Smith may veto the bill."
"**Mr.** President, will you veto the bill?"

"Captain Smith's ship is in danger of sinking."
<s>"**Mr.** Captain, will your ship sink?"</s>
"Captain, will your ship sink?"

"Queen Elizabeth has posthumously pardoned Professor Turing."
<s>"Queen, why did you pardon Professor Turing?"</s>

<s>"President, will you veto the bill?"</s>

<s>**Mr.** Professor, are you guilty of the offense?</s>
Professor, are you guilty of the offense?

We do not say "Mr. Captain" although we do say "Mr. President" and "Mr. Secretary"; we do not use "Queen" or "President" in the second person although we do use "Captain" and "Judge" and "Professor" in that way. (In some translations from English into German, I've seen "Herr Minister" used to translate "Mr. Secretary" and "Herr Kapitän" to translate "Captain", both used in the second person.

Is there some pattern here, or would a foreigner learning English have to learn each one separately?

Comment: In my opinion, English seems to be more complicated in this regard than German (where you can add Herr in front of most titles) or French (similarly Monsieur or Monsieur le, Madame or Madame la).  Titles of nobility (Queen, Duke) or high religious status (Cardinal, Archbishop) are especially complicated.

Comment: With the queen, you would have to use _Your Majesty_ of course. (Your stricken-out “President…” example seems to have been displaced from its fellow.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet : It is indeed so displaced, but I thought it was premature to exhibit that example for some examples like "Captain" appeared in which that form is standard.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In formal conversation with the Queen, *Your Majesty* is appropriate, but informally she is quite happy with *Ma'am*, as long as you say it in a way that rhymes with *ham*. She cannot abide it when people say it to rhyme with *farm*.

Comment: @WS2 I thought you were supposed to use _Your Majesty_ the first time you address her, and then _Ma’am_ for repeated addresses.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think that's probably right. It would not be a good idea to continue with *Your Majesty* any more than *Ma'am* to rhyme with *farm*. Equally, and I heard this from someone who was introduced to the Prince of Wales, it is not a good idea for men to bow too deeply, or women to courtesy too low. He and his wife were told that a nod from him and a slight bob from her would be all that would be required. Though when Theresa May went in to kiss hands as the new Prime Minister, I did notice (on the TV) that she gave a deep and elegant courtesy.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think that should be spelled *curtsey*. It is difficult to tell from the OED which is the current, and which the obsolete spelling - *curtsey* or *courtesy*.

Comment: @WS2 : My understanding has been that the first time you address her in any particular encounter you call her "Your Majesty", but after that during the same conversation you say "Ma'am".

Comment: @MichaelHardy As long as it rhymes with *ham*.

Comment: When First Lady Nancy Reagan shook hands with the queen rather than curtseying, some people made an issue of the matter and the palace issued as statement that the first lady's conduct was neither unprecedented nor improper.

Comment: @MichaelHardy It is often said that Reagan was the US President whose company she enjoyed most (Trump will be the 13th of her reign, which began with Truman). And that for the simple reason that he knew a lot about horses. Apparently horses were the chief topic of conversation between them.

Comment: As long as we are off-topic, [Miss Manners](https://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/style/miss-manners-for-americans-no-bowing-allowed/2011/06/17/AGd56ivH_story.html?utm_term=.a8b15ebf8008) says US citizens do not curtsey to the Queen.

Answer (score 2):

This is unfortunately a situation in which there is no systematic approach, and every high-ranking official's form of address will need to be learned / memorized individually.  (Note that as part of the culture for most English speaking countries, you will use a person's name except in situations where the person has a very high official rank)

That said, I suspect that the "Mr/Madam President" form of address likely uses "Mr/Madam" to emphasize that this is neither a title of nobility, nor a rank of military, nor a member of the clergy.  "Mister" is usually a common form of address (eg, "My friend, Mr Rogers"), so its use here is to distinguish it from other uncommon forms of address.  But even knowing this, you cannot necessarily apply it as a rule to other situations.

Comment: I have no idea how I edited your post. I tried to edit my post. Instead, it edited yours and deleted my post. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It is established in tradition as to how to address royalty.

My suspicion as to how to address American political holders is whether the title is retained...George W. Bush is still called Mr. President. Hillary Clinton is still called Madam Secretary.